# Can My.Log.WriteEntry write to other than application log (asp.net 4.5)

Tags: asp.net, logging

I am moving an old asp.net 4.5 web forms application to the cloud. I do not have permission to write to the Windows Event log. So I commented out the section in web.config that writes to the Event Log using type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener. If I uncomment the web.config section that uses System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener I could use that if it captures event log entries like the other ones does. I write in this this VB application using My.Log.WriteEntry and for a lot of reasons I do not want to change all those locations in the source. So would that work, or does that listener not capture my writeentry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you *should* be able to simply change which listener is enabled. See this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/log-info/walkthrough-changing-where-my-application-log-writes-information).